# Marklogic: Privilege needed to add response header

Tags: xquery, marklogic

When I try to set a response header `content disposition` as attachmnent and give it a filename (consider `abc.xlsx`), then marklogic throws an exception message saying that privilege required to set response header. For the application, I set `Authentication` to `application-level`, because I cannot set it to basic or digest or anything else. So what is the list of probable alternatives? I want to prompt a download dialogue to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

Go the admin UI and find the name of the user that your appserver is running as.  By default, probably nobody.  Then go to the security section in the admin UI, find the user, and give that user the privilege to set response headers.  Alternatively, you could use a different user that already has that privilege (or  you could create a new one).

Comment: Note that you must set exec privileges for a role, not directly for a user. The `nobody` user has no roles, so you will probably want to create a new `default-app` role and assign it to a corresponding `default-app` user. http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/security might be helpful, and it's worth mentioning that this design pattern is baked into the roxy framework: https://github.com/marklogic/roxy

Comment: Thanks, Mike, that's spot on.